# ffmpeg stream_loop CPU 100%

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a pretty simple stream_loop running out to an rtmp server.  I even tried to optimize the files so it didn't have to encode but I must be doing something wrong

Here's my code:

play.sh

```sh
ffmpeg \
  -stream_loop -1 \
  -i playlist1.txt \
  -c:v copy \
  -c:a copy \
  -f flv "rtmp://..."
```

playlist1.txt

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file 'tracks/001.mp4'
file 'playlist2.txt'
```

playlist2.txt

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file 'tracks/002.mp4'
file 'playlist1.txt'
```

I have it in 2 playlists to make it infinite, read that somewhere.

I get a constant log of this
`Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream`

Here's my output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1ubuntu1~18.04.york0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55c005b43700] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'playlist1.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 406 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 278 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 10240 tbn, 20 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://......':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 640x360, q=2-31, 278 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 1k tbn, 10240 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55c005bca200] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter34x    
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55c005c94480] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter03x    
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55c005bcd7c0] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter91x    
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55c005bcb780] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter80x    
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55c005b4ca00] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter78x    
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55c005b4c900] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter83x    
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55c005bcba40] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter84x
```

my **guess** is these video files are 1:1.  I tried re-encoding to force them to 10fps, but i notice `278 kb/s` and `77 kb/s`

Any help appreciated thanks!

Comment: Don't do recursive nesting. Two child playlists - each referencing one video file. And one parent playlist listing the two child playlists.

Comment: @Gyan ah i see - how do i make it loop forever then?

Comment: The stream loop will do  that.